# Constructive Proof- How to Start?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, constructive-mathematics

A rational number can be written as $\frac{p}{q}$, where $p$ is an integer, $q$ is an integer, and $q \neq 0$. Suppose that $r_0$ and $r_1$ are rational numbers, and that $r_0 < r_1$. Prove that there is a rational number $u$ such that $r_0 < u < r_1$. Your proof must be constructive, and your answer must briefly explain why it is constructive.

I just want to know how to start this proof. I am confused where I can get an algorithm from this.

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem? What have you tried? What paths seem as if they could work and which ones seem as if they don't work at all? What about the problem is confusing you?

Comment: I've tried setting r0 and r1 to p/q and x/y respectively, and u to a/b. I don't know where to go from there though.

Comment: You've got a good start. If I give you two numbers x and y, can you think of some numbers that are in between? Can you think of a number that's exactly halfway in between? If x and y are rational, could you show that some convenient in-between numbers are also rational?

Comment: You’re thinking too hard. If I give you the numbers $\frac{1}{2}$ and $\frac{3}{5}$ and told you to find a rational number between them, how would you do it?

Comment: May be you could start with something that is visual i.e. a real number line and mark the rational points $r_{0}$ and $r_{1}$. If this situation is still uncomfortable, then try replacing $r_{0}$ and $r_{1}$ by some particular rational numbers. Then think how a rational number could be constructed using those particular rational numbers. Lastly, can you generalise that your method for constructing (in the particular case above ) works for any two rational numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $$ r= \frac {r_1+r_2}{2}$$

Suppose  $$r_1 = \frac {m_1}{n_1} \le \frac {m_2}{n_2}= r_2  $$

Then $$ r= \frac {m_1 n_2 +m_2 n_1}{2n_1n_2}$$ is rational.

Since $r$ is the average of  $r_1$ and $r_2$,

$$  r_1 =\frac {m_1}{n_1} \le  \frac {m_1 n_2 +m_2 n_1}{2n_1n_2} \le \frac {m_2}{n_2}= r_2$$

Thus between any two rational numbers there exists a rational number.

Answer (score 1):

The midpoint $$\frac{r_0+r_1}{2}$$ seems a good candidate and it's constructive. You have to show that it is rational and that is between $r_0$ and $r_1$.